# Check whether the file retrieved from Firestore is empty

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nsdata

I need to make sure I can always feedback an Image object from the backend, but the thing is that it's not guaranteed that every query can get the image using the following function.

```
let store = Storage.storage().reference()
let imageRef = store.child("profile_Photos").child(uid)
imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 64 * 64, completion: { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Encountered error: \(error) when getting image")
        self.currentPhoto = Image(systemName: "person").resizable()
    } else {
        // "data" can be 0 bytes
        // do something to judge whether it is 0 or not
        // in order to avoid any error in the next line
        self.currentPhoto = Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: data!)!).resizable()
    }
})
```

What could I do to replace the comments?

Comment: When you say it could be 0 bytes, does that mean the file exists with 0 bytes? Or does that mean the file doesn't exist at all.

Comment: That's a good suggesttion, Jay. Right now I only consider that my collection is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data` has an `isEmpty` boolean so if you insist on this extra layer of safety then you can simply read it:

```
let store = Storage.storage().reference()
let imageRef = store.child("profile_Photos").child(uid)
imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 64 * 64, completion: { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Encountered error: \(error) when getting image")
        self.currentPhoto = Image(systemName: "person").resizable()
    } else if let data = data,
              !data.isEmpty,
              let img = UIImage(data: data).resizable() {
        self.currentPhoto = img
    }
})
```

You can include `UIImage` in the conditional or not, it doesn't matter so much in the practical sense since `UIImageView` takes optional images, but it's an extra layer of safety which is what you're apparently after.